# Breezing Forms component not saving quick mode form

Tags: joomla, breezingforms

Iam using a Breezing forms component of joomla on a newly developed website, but the problem is wen i create a Contact us form from quick mode with all the fields, textboxes, text areas etc............but after all the things are done and i try to save the form it is not saving, like after clicking save and navigate away from the page and again i go to quick mode forms
there is no form saved............i tried this on my local version of the website it is working fine there but cant understand why it is not saving on the online version of it.......am i missing something.

any help will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error messages either on the page or in the logs?

Comment: @ Blair McMillan, iam not getting any error msg in the joomla backend....but wen i give the name with which i created the form...on the page it is giving the msg "The form does not exist"

Comment: I have the same problem (on BF version 1.7.3 Joomla 1.6.3) and have just raised ticket 2919D7 - have you raised any ticket?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was so simple so that I was a little bit ashamed.

Just under the menu line in `beezingforms` - managing forms page, there is a pulldown menu named `Package`. Select `Quickmodeforms` of `easymodeformsfrom` from the pull down and all the forms I thought where not made are showing on the screen.